# How to accept private repository ownership on GitHub?

Tags: github

How to start a private GitHub repository ownership transfer on GitHub is [relatively clear](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository#transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-user-account).

But when we follow this process the accepting account doesn't show any signs of transfer and there is no button or link to click to finish the transfer process. The accepting account also doesn't get any email notifications.

In the sending account the "Transfer" is being shown as pending.

How to accept a pending private GitHub repository ownership transfer?

Comment: The recipient should get an email with a link to `/repositories/transfers/<some-id>` - if they don't, this is a matter for GitHub support rather than SO.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out (as I was expecting) not to be a GitHub issue.
The receiving account was having the valid email address as not primary. The primary email address was not valid any longer and the secondary email address didn't receive any email notifications.

Cleaning up receiving account email addresses and setting the the valid primary email address allowed to transfer the repository ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the email worked well for me. If you don't have an email setup then you won't receive a transfer link.